# Cannot get Google maps to display in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a simple Chrome extension that uses HTML5 geolocation to show a map with your position on a map have got the geolocation to work but when I try to add it to maps it does not  work. It says `uncaught error google undefined`.

```
{
  "name": "gary  ",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "geo extension",

  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "main1.html",
   "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
   "geolocation",
   "https://maps.googleapis.com/*"
  ]
   }
```

The JavaScript:

```
x = navigator.geolocation;
  x.getCurrentPosition(success,failure);
  function success(position){

  var mylat = position.coords.latitude;
  var mylong = position.coords.longitude;

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylong);

  var mapOptions ={
   zoom:16,
   center: coords,
   maptypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  }
  function failure(){
  $('#lat').html("<p>it does not work<p>");
  }
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=initializ‌​e">          </script> 
  <script src="geo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>


<body>
<div style = "width: 700px; height: 700px;" >
<div id="lat"></div>
<div id="map"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you get the map to show up if you just stick in a random map center and put it outside the success callback?

Comment: Including your `main1.html` is more important.

Comment: Added the html as requested

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a `$(document).ready()`. I have a feeling Maps API just does not finish loading.

Comment: It is inside the success callback, which map centre would you recommend? And the $(document).ready() do you mean in the html? if that is the case that would  not work as chrome extensions do not allow in-line script.